# Copy Builds from one pipeline to other pipeline in azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-rest-api

We have two Team projects. Project A and Project B. We have a situation where we need to copy pipelines and its builds from one project to other project.so we will be able to export and import the pipeline but unable to copy individual builds.

is it really possible to copy/migrate all individual builds from old pipeline to new pipeline?

if yes, what could be the process?

Comment: it's yaml pipelines or UI pipelines?

Comment: Hi @ShaykiAbramczyk
We have actually both UI and yml pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

We can follow the below steps to clone the pipeline by customizing it according to our requirements:

1. Edit the pipeline.
2. Copy the YAML format and can be used for new pipeline.
3. Customize the new pipeline accordingly.

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/customize-pipeline?view=azure-devops) to understand about customizing a pipeline. And [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/clone-import-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for clone pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you could not copy the pipelines with all individual builds.

Azure DevOps now only supports to copy pipelines from one project to another, you can follow the steps in this doc: [Clone or import a pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/clone-import-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

I can fully understand your requirement. I suggest that you can create a suggestion ticket in the [this site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?from=email&viewtype=all&space=21&entry=suggestion.).

Thanks for your understanding.